# find duplicate entries in mysql and php and enlist all the entries one other below

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get all the entries from mysql table having duplicate mobile_no and email_id, i tried the following query but no luck

```
SELECT * FROM duplicate WHERE (mobile_no = (SELECT mobile_no FROM duplicate)) ORDER BY id DESC
```

BUT IT RETUNS 'Subquery returns more than 1 row'

please suggest some query.
Column Names:
mobile_no, email_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the whole row, you can do this...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  duplicate
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM duplicates   AS lookup
           WHERE lookup.id <> duplicate.id
             AND (  lookup.email_id  = duplicate.email_id
                 OR lookup.mobile_no = duplicate.mobile_no
             )
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(mobile_no) FROM duplicate GROUP BY mobile_no HAVING COUNT(mobile_no) > 1;
```

See this turtorial here http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find-duplicate-values/

Comment: From the manual for MySQL : MySQL 5.7.5 and up implements detection of functional dependence. If the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY SQL mode is enabled (which it is by default), MySQL rejects queries for which the select list, HAVING condition, or ORDER BY list refer to nonaggregated columns that are neither named in the GROUP BY clause nor are functionally dependent on them. (Before 5.7.5, MySQL does not detect functional dependency and ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is not enabled by default. For a description of pre-5.7.5 behavior, see the MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual.)

Comment: In other words, even MySQL no longer (from 5.7.5 on-wards) allows you to select fields that are not part of an aggregate or the group by list.  Unless you turn `only_full_group_by` off, which they advise should be left on.